# Is it possible to use a USB flash drive to serve files locally to a browser?

Tags: python, web-services, usb

Using just python, is it possible to possible to use a USB flash drive to serve files locally to a browser, and save information off the online web?

Ideally I would only need python.

Where would I start?

Comment: Ive read this question several times and I'm still not sure exactly what you want. Is the USB local to the browser, or the server? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Say you are in Afghanistan now with your laptop relying heavily on some mapping website such as a customized Google Maps with special overlays. Then you tell me where you currently are has no Internet connection. So then I just mail you a USB with all the key data of that area you are in served to your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use portable python on the flash drive. [Portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com/) And code some sort of little python webserver, handling get and post extending the BaseHTTPRequestHandler class.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem much different then serving files from a local hard drive.  You could map the thumbdrive to always be something not currently used on your machine (like U:).